# PyQt6 Create Playlist

Tags: qmediaplayer, pyqt6

How can I create playlist in PyQt6?

I can only set one media with `setSource()`:

```
self.soundUrl = QUrl.fromLocalFile("4k-is-2.mp4")
self.player.setSource(self.soundUrl)
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't properly read that you referred to Qt6. As explained in the [Qt 6.2 release](https://www.qt.io/blog/qt-multimedia-in-qt-6) post, the playlist functionality has been removed and will be reinstated in a future version. Qt 6.3 will be probably out this month, so you may be lucky, otherwise you'll probably have to wait for 6.4 at least, which will be probably released after the next summer.

Comment: Yah, PyQt6.3 Don't have.  "QMediaPlayer does not do any playlist handling anymore in Qt 6."

Comment: See https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtmultimedia-changes-qt6.html from Removed Features

Comment: I suggest you just use a list

Comment: @musicamante Did you get the solution this problem.

Comment: @BikiranDas As explained above, the feature has been removed (and it seems like they are not interested in restoring it). Use a list and implement proper handling through QMediaPlayer signals.

Comment: @musicamante how could i use this feature in PyQt6, my application is being created on pyqt6 library. is there a easy way i can create the QMediaPlaylist Class for PyQt6

Comment: @BikiranDas There are many possible ways to do so. I suggest you to take your time and study the QMediaPlayer documentation, then try to implement it on your own, if you don't succeed or get unexpected results, post a new question with a proper [mre] based on your attempts.